# How to open submenu on hover of main menu?

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

Hi I am making menu and submenu. I have made menu with all effect. I want to open submenu on hover of menu item, but it's not opening; it shows me already open.

My [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/n7J8x/)

```css
#companymenu {
    background-color: #999;
    height:35px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.companymenuul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.companymenuli {
    float: left;
    display:block;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.alisting {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.aactive {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #999;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
.companymenuli a:hover {
    color:#C63;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:24px;
    padding-right: 23px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #999;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
.caret {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 4px solid #fff;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    content:"";
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    background-image:url(images/topnav-arrow-down-white-ie6.png)no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
    _display: inline;
    _zoom: 1;
    _width: 7px;
    _height: 4px;
    _margin-top: 8px;
    _margin-left: 5px;
    _line-height: 4px;
    _border: none;
    _vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div id="companymenu">
    <ul class="companymenuul">
        <li class="companymenuli aactive"><a class="alisting">Home</a></li>
        <li class="companymenuli"><a class="alisting">Product Categories<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="companymenuli"><a class="alisting">Company Profile  <b class="caret"></b></a>
        </li>
        <li class="companymenuli"><a class="alisting">Contacts</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to open `<ul>` on hover of Product Categories `<li>`

Comment: Very dirty code, here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/n7J8x/5/

Comment: @Mr.Alien - why dirty code , sir ? Tell me so I can change my code and make it more effective. Thank You.

Comment: You can refer my example and cut short your code excessively :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Okay, I have given some effects on hover that's why code is more and some extra lines are also there I ll make change in it, Thank You sir.

Comment: Yea, and you welcome :) wish u luck with your project or learning :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien - getting problem http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/n7J8x/16/  the company introduction should remain at it's place but it's behave unexpected.

Comment: Don't merge my code with yours straight away, understand which properties are necessary, which aren't and accordingly compress your code

Comment: @Mr.Alien  -yes sir I ll update mine with your new and compress code, I want to remove that problem occur on hover of menu items.

Comment: Thats because of the `padding` values on `:hover` http://jsfiddle.net/n7J8x/20/

Answer (score 10):

Are you looking for something like this? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7J8x/1/)

Give your submenu a class and add `display:none;` to it. After you can give your hover `display:block;`

So you have something like this:

```css
.submenu{
    display:none;
}

.companymenuli:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<li class="companymenuli"><a class="alisting">Product Categories  <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

For removing the bullets just add `list-style-type:none;` to your `submenu li` tag. Here your updated fiddle:

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7J8x/6/)

Answer (score 3):

add this css in your existing css:

```
.companymenuli ul {
    display:none;
}

.companymenuli:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try below `HTML` and `CSS`

```
<li class="companymenuli"><a class="alisting">Product Categories  <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="ul">
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                </ul>                       
</li>

<style>
.ul
{
    display:none;
}
.companymenuli:hover .ul
{
    display:block
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution Here

http://jsfiddle.net/n7J8x/4/

By default hide Sub Menus

```
.submenu{
     display:none;
}
```

Open Submenus on hover of Main Menus

```
.companymenuul > li:hover ul{
     display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fully Solved [answer fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/n7J8x/23/).
I have solved it byself.

Thank You to everyone who help me or not.

```
.companymenuli:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    background-color: #999;
    color:#FFF;
}
.submenu{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    width: 120px;
}
.submenu li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
.m-header {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    breakpoint: 768,
    format: "multitoggle"
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #1b9bff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eeeeee;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #eeeeee;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eeeeee;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #1b9bff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #eeeeee;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen li:hover > ul > li {
  height: auto;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 35px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right ul ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 17px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  top: 23px;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  top: 23px;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
  background: #0190ff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 19px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #eeeeee;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:after {
  top: 15px;
  right: 13px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 22px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:before {
  top: 12px;
  right: 16px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.select-list {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- MenuMaker Plugin -->
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/menumaker/menumaker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> Product Categories</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1.1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1.2</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.3</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 2.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 2.3</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 3.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 3.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 3.3</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Company Profile</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.companymenuul .companymenuli aactive:hover ul{ 
     display:block;
}
```