# Problem with optgroup working with my website contact, does optgroup work? what should I use?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that consists of "Home", "About", "Contact", "Profile". When hovering over "Profile" I'm hoping I can show a submenu with links to my Github/Facebook accounts etc. How can I do this?

I'm sorry if somebody has already answered this but I tried looking for some information and I couldn't find anything that worked.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

.top {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #dfe3ee;
}

.top a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.top a:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: darkred;
}

.active {
  background-color: #44E6F2;
  color: Ivory;
}

.top input[type=text] {
  float: right;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 250px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#sub1 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

#sub2 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="Top">
      <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#profile">Profile</a>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left:16px">
    </div>
  </header>
  <nav>
  </nav>
  <main>
  </main>
  <aside>
  </aside>
  <footer>
    <center><sub id="sub2">Contact Me:</sub></center>
    <center><sub id="sub1">foo@example.com</sub></center>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open submenu on hover of main menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742401/how-to-open-submenu-on-hover-of-main-menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want a submenu with links to social media platforms to appear when you hover over 'Profile' in the menu. There's several ways to do this, most of them involve a little Javascript, but you can do it with pure CSS, here's an example:

```css
/* Hide Dropdowns by Default */

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  /* the height of the main nav */
}


/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}


/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */

nav ul ul li {
  width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">WordPress</a>
      <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Also see https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/xhiJH.