# Wordpress Submenu on header menu not showing

Tags: css, wordpress, code-cleanup

I seem to be having a code clash that I can not find on the website https://integritysolutionscentre.com/

I have taken over this site that at least 3 different developers developed, the issues I am having are, after disconnecting the UBER MENU plugin, the submenu of the WordPress based menu set up on the header is not dropping down. As you will see it showing in the sticky menu as well as the footer, only the header menu is disabled, I have searched through the 214 lines and taken out all i thought it could be, I have also tried CSS for adding the submenu again, nothing...

one of many codes I have tried to add to the CSS that have not worked are:
[How to open submenu on hover of main menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742401/how-to-open-submenu-on-hover-of-main-menu)

The CSS in the site where I believe the clash is coming from is below: (thank you in advance for your insight)

```
`\*/
.fl-page-nav-wrap {
background-color: #316b99;
}

.fl-page-header-primary .fl-logo-img {
height: auto !important;
width: 218px !important;
}

div#hide-events {
display: none;
}

input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
width: 30%;
padding-left: 1;
margin-right: 9%;
}

.wpcf7-recaptcha \> div {
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left:0%;
margin-right:9%

}

.corporate-partner .card {
min-height: 490px;
}

.fl-page-header .header-tel {
display: none;
}

.fl-page-header .aus-nz-flag {
/*display: none;*/
}

.page-header-tagline-container {
display: none;
}

.header-row-slogan {
display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
.header-row-right {
margin-top: 50px;
text-align: right;
}
}

.single .fl-node-59b1e671982c1 {
display: none;
}

.top20 img{
max-width: 200px !important;
height: 150px;
}

.fl-page-nav-search {
display: none !important;
}

\#hero-row .fl-row-content-wrap {
/*padding: 0;*/
}

\#hero-row div#yui_3_18_1_1_1623997572243_380 {
max-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

\#hero-row .fl-col-group-equal-height {
height: 100%;
}

\#hero-row .fl-row-content {
height: 100%;
}

\#hero-row .fl-col-content {
/*padding: 0 100px;*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1098px) {
\#hero-row .fl-col {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1030px) {
.home .fl-node-59b1d2e483ff4 {
width: 100%;
}
.card img {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
.fl-node-59b9c1600e6ec, .fl-node-59b9c47327898, .fl-node-59b9c63999337, .fl-node-59b9bbb6f1879, .fl-node-59b9f0c263cbf, .fl-node-59b766cf53393 {
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: -1px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
.fl-node-60cd34741932f.fl-col \> .fl-col-content {
margin-bottom: -1px;
margin-top: -1px;
}

    .fl-module img {
    width: 100%;

}

.fl-builder-content .fl-node-59b9bbb6f1879 {
width: 100%;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.fl-page-header a:hover, .fl-page-header a:focus, .fl-page-header a:hover \*, .fl-page-header a:focus \*, .fl-page-header a.fa:hover, .fl-page-header a.fa:focus {
color: #fff;
}

.fl-page-nav-wrap .container {
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
}
.fl-node-59b766cf538c1.fl-module \> .fl-module-content {
margin-left: 20px;
}
.fl-node-59b766cf539a0.fl-module \> .fl-module-content {
margin-left: 20px;
}
.fl-page-nav-bottom .fl-page-header-logo {
text-align: center;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.header-row-right {
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
text-align: center;
}
.home .fl-node-60cb1cfecd642 {
width: 100%;
}
.home .fl-node-60cb1cfecd648 {
width: 100%;
}
.home .card .card-height {
height: 20px !important;
}
.home .fl-node-59b1d2e484035 {
width: 100%;
}

    #hero-row .fl-col-small:not(.fl-col-small-full-width) {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    #hero-row .fl-col-content {
        /*padding: 0 50px;*/
    }
        
    #achievements-row img {
        max-width: 50%;
    }

.fl-col-small:not(.fl-col-small-full-width) {
max-width: 100%;
}

.fl-node-60cd34741932f.fl-col \> .fl-col-content {
padding-right: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}

}

\#selling-power-modal .selling-power-modal {
background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/2021-Selling-Power-Top-Sales-Training-Company-Logo-FINAL-SML-1.png');
background-size: auto;
height: 100px;
background-color: transparent;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 0;
background-position: center;
background-size: 146px 100px;
}

\#bronze-stevie-winner-modal .bronze-stevie-winner-modal {
background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/integrity-solutions-new-SASCS21_Bronze_Winner-SML.png');
background-size: auto;
height: 100px;
background-color: transparent;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 0;
background-position: center;  
}

\#gold-stevie-winner-modal .gold-stevie-winner-modal {
background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Stevie-Awards_2020_Gold_Winner-SML.png');
background-size: auto;
height: 100px;
background-color: transparent;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 0;
background-position: center;  
}

\#top-20-modal .top-20-modal {
background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/2021-Top20-Print-Medium_sales-enablement-training-SML.png');
background-size: auto;
height: 100px;
background-color: transparent;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 0;
background-position: center;  
}

.fl-tabs-label {
margin-bottom: 6px;
margin-top: 6px;
}`
```

Comment: Looks like you fixed it?

Comment: Hi Junky, it's only the header menu - it's not working on my side still - the one with the dark blue background, the footer and sticky menu are working.